# Any way we can improve the performance of saving/loading a .xml, especially when the .xml in big file size

Tags: xml, performance, com, xml-parsing

we have a application, and all the data was stored in a .xml file. when users keep working, the .xml file will keep growing, and normally, it will get up to 10M KB, and some times, it will growing to 80M KB. Is there any way we can do to improve the saving/loading performance around the xml file?

Right now, we are using Micorsoft MSXML.Document to load the .xml, and using XPath to operate on it.
And I am thinking if it is possible to convert the .xml into a binary file, then it can save time when loading? or any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switching from a DOM based API (such as `Msxml2.DOMDocument` when using MSXML) to a stream based API (eg. `Msxml2.SAXXMLReader`) will avoid parsing and loading the whole XML document into memory. It will also avoid the highly linked nature of a DOM object graph (all of those next/previous/first-child/… links add up to a significant overhead).

However this means no XPath and a very different programming model.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Currently, the bottleneck of the performance is opening the .xml, and the other parts are in-memory operations, which is fast enough. Yes, SAX can be consider as an option, however the refactor work will be very large for me. I am not sure but guess if there is any technology similar like serialization, that we can persist the XML Document into file, then restore into memory. maybe it would have better performance then opening the original .xml file each time. :-)
Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisLiu There are lots of serialisation options if you were in Java or .NET. There might be for native code (and if you're not using native code or legacy (VB6) why use MSXML?) but I don't know of anything personally. Have you considered a database?